# Build custom kernel snap for Ubuntu Core 22

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

The goal is to use Ubuntu Core 22 on IoT devices as a base. I need to include a custom proprietary driver as kernel module. I tried the following guide
[Building a kernel snap](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/kernel-building) but this seems to target the base core18. The [kernel plugin](https://snapcraft.io/docs/kernel-plugin) is only available for core18 based snaps.

1. Is is possible to build a custom kernel snap with core22?
2. Does the kernel snap with core18 works also with Ubuntu Core 22?
3. Why is there no support for core 22?